# Criar acesso FTP para um diretório virtual na Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-azure

Tenho um Aplicativo Web na Azure e criei uma pasta interna como diretório virtual para que um desenvolvedor terceirizado implante um sistema contratado.
Estou com grande dificuldade em criar um FTP que tenha acesso somente ao diretório /comercial dentro da hospedagem.
Alguém sabe como criar essas credenciais ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enfim, a Azure não permite criar um usuário para uma subpasta.
Foi necessário criar um recurso em minha aplicação em que a pessoa pudesse fazer o upload do projeto em .zip e o processo descompactava dentro da pasta.
Problema resolvido.

Answer (score 3):

A Azure não implementa o protocolo FTP nos seus websites. A ferramenta é outra. Chama-se WebMatrix.

[Você pode baixá-la aqui](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/).

---

**EDIT**

Acho que esta resposta defasou. [Agora existe uma maneira de publicar via FTP também](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-mysql-deploy-use-ftp/), mas não recomendo para o ASP.NET MVC porque boa parte das configurações automáticas são feitas pelo Web Deploy.

Comment: Cigano, Azure WebApp implementam SIM FTP em seus websites. As publicações podem ser feitas via FTP, WebDeploy ou Implementação Contínua a partir do VSTS, GitHub, DropBox, OneDrive, etc. Aqui tem um exemplo de [Publicação no Azure via FTP](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-mysql-deploy-use-ftp/)

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi Obrigado pelo link. Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Legal, Cigano, tirei o downvote. Porém, as configurações automática também funcionam quando se faz deploy via FTP. O Visual Studio primeiro faz o build em release, aplica todas as configurações de pré compilação e transformação de *.configs, cria um pacote publicável e sobe esse pacote via FTP. O processo realmente é PIOR - não me agrada -, mas o produto final que é entregado é exatamente o mesmo do WebDeploy.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi Quase. O cabeçalho de migração automática do Entity Framework é colocado pela interface do Publish. Dá pra colocar manual também. Eu não queria ir muito a fundo nesta resposta porque sai muito do propósito da pergunta. Apenas comentei por causa da tag, que está como ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel,

O serviço de Azure WebApp fornece sim suporte à publicação via FTP, porém ele te dá acesso à toda a área de publicação e não tem suporte para especificar acesso à um pasta específica.

O que é recomendado fazer neste seu cenário é criar dois serviços de WebApp:

- SuaAppPrincipal.azurewebsites.net
- SuaSolucaoTerceirizada.azurewebsites.net

E então você organiza seus endereços com subdomínios.

- www.dominioprincipal.com.br
- solucaoterceirizada.dominioprincipal.com.br

Agora, para atender algo do tipo `dominioprincipal.com.br/solucaoterceirizada`, apenas se a terceirizada te enviar os fontes, vocês podem fazer o *merge* das duas aplicações e subir em uma única hospedagem.

Porém, por ser terceirizada, eu prefiro o primeiro cenário, assim a solução terceirizada - que, teoricamente, você não tem controle como a forma que foi desenvolvida - irá rodar sob um host independente da principal. Assim, se ela tiver algum problema e cair, não irá derrubar junto a app principal. E vice-versa.

Comment: Concordo com sua solução inclusive pratico ela em outros casos, mas especificamente neste precisava ser publicado em /solucaoterceirizada.
A solução foi criar um processo em minha aplicação onde ele pode realizar o upload diretamente para dentro da pasta, mesmo com os riscos.